# Three.js: Rotate object with lookAt() while located at the current lookAt() position

Tags: three.js, rotation

I'm trying to implement a simple turn-around-and-move feature with Three.js. On mouse click, the object is supposed to first turn around and then move to the clicked location.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Candleout/pen/ZExvYJW)

The rotation is achieved with raycasting and lookAt(). It works by itself and it always works on the first click. If you remove the translation, it works continuously. The issue occurs when rotation and translation are implemented together. If you click a second time, after the object has moved to the previous clicked location, it doesn't rotate as expected. Depending on the mouse location it can flip to the other side without rotating at all.

Clarification: When you click the first time, notice how the object slowly and steadily turns around to face that direction? But the second time, after the object has moved, the rotation is quicker and/or flimsier or it simply flips over and there is no rotation at all. It depends on where you click in relation to the object.

I believe the issue stems from trying to implement lookAt while being located at the current lookAt location? If I stop the translation half way, the next rotation will work better. But of course I need it to go all the way.

I'm somewhat lost on how to proceed with this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
/*** Setup scene ***/

let width = 800
let height = 600
let scene
let renderer
let worldAxis
let box
let angle
let boxAxes

scene = new THREE.Scene()
worldAxis = new THREE.AxesHelper(200);
scene.add(worldAxis);

// Setup renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({alpha: true, antialias: true})
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

// Setup camera
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(
                width / - 2, // left
                width / 2, // right
                height / 2, // top
                height / - 2, // bottom
                0, // near
                1000 ); // far
camera.position.set(0, 0, 500)
camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

// Setup box
let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 15, 15, 15 );
let material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: "grey" } );
box = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
box.position.set(100, 150, 0)
box.lookAt(getPointOfIntersection(new THREE.Vector2(0, 0)))
addAngle()
boxAxes = new THREE.AxesHelper(50);
box.add(boxAxes)
scene.add(box)

renderer.render(scene, camera);

/*** Setup animation ***/

let animate = false
let currentlyObservedPoint = new THREE.Vector2();
let rotationIncrement = {}
let translationIncrement = {}
let frameCount = 0

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let mousePosForRotate = getMousePos(event.clientX, event.clientY)
  rotationIncrement.x = (mousePosForRotate.x - currentlyObservedPoint.x)/100
  rotationIncrement.y = (mousePosForRotate.y - currentlyObservedPoint.y)/100
  
  let mousePosForTranslate = getMousePosForTranslate(event)
  translationIncrement.x = (mousePosForTranslate.x - box.position.x)/100
  translationIncrement.y = (mousePosForTranslate.y - box.position.y)/100
  animate = true
})

function animationLoop() {
  if (animate === true) {
    if (frameCount < 100) {
      rotate()
    } else if (frameCount < 200) {
      translate()
    } else {
      animate = false
      frameCount = 0
    }
    frameCount++
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(animationLoop) 
}

function rotate() {
  currentlyObservedPoint.x += rotationIncrement.x
  currentlyObservedPoint.y += rotationIncrement.y
  
  let pointOfIntersection = getPointOfIntersection(currentlyObservedPoint)
  box.lookAt(pointOfIntersection)
  addAngle()
}

function translate() {
  box.position.x += translationIncrement.x
  box.position.y += translationIncrement.y
}

function getMousePos(x, y) {
  let mousePos = new THREE.Vector3(
    (x / width) * 2 - 1,
    - (y / height) * 2 + 1,
    0)
  return mousePos
}

function getMousePosForTranslate(event) {
  let rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  let mousePos = { x: event.clientX - rect.top, y: event.clientY - rect.left }

  let vec = getMousePos(mousePos.x, mousePos.y)
  vec.unproject(camera);
  vec.sub(camera.position).normalize();
  let distance = - camera.position.z / vec.z;
  let pos = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0);
  pos.copy(camera.position).add(vec.multiplyScalar(distance));
  
  return pos
}

function getPointOfIntersection(mousePos) {
  let plane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 1), 0);
  let pointOfIntersection = new THREE.Vector3()
  const raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
  
  raycaster.setFromCamera(mousePos, camera)
  raycaster.ray.intersectPlane(plane, pointOfIntersection)
  
  return pointOfIntersection
}

function addAngle() {
  let angle = box.rotation.x - 32
  box.rotation.x = angle
}

animationLoop()
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/105/three.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Could you better describe how to reproduce this bug and what to look for? It seems fine to me when trying it.

Comment: When you click the first time, notice how the object slowly and steadily turns around to face that direction? But the second time, after the object has moved, the rotation is quicker and/or flimsier or it simply flips over and there is no rotation at all. It depends on where you click in relation to the object. You should be able to reproduce this by simly clicking more than one time.

Comment: @Berthur Were you able to reproduce it?

Comment: I suppose I the animation started to behave in unexpected ways, yes. But I haven't had time to debug your code. Have you looked at other's animation examples?

Comment: @Berthur I would love to take inspiration from a similar example or follow a tutorial if I could find one. I have a feeling there are better approaches. For some reason it has been hard finding something similar.